# Send email from JS code , with the help of PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, email

I want to send an email from the JS code ,with the help of PHP .

```
function validateForm(){


    // sending a mail 
    $.get("../sendMail.php");


    // more code

}
```

And I have a file called `sendMail.php` , that's stored on the server :

**sendMail.php :**

```
<?php
session_start();  
if(($_POST['name'] == '') || ($_POST['phone'] == '') || ($_POST['email'] == '')) {
/*------
echo 'Complete the forms correctly <br>
Click <a href="contact.php">here</a> to return on contact us page.'; 
-------*/
header("location:index.php");
} else {

$to = 'johnny@gmail.com';  
$send_date = date('d-m-Y H:i:s');
$subject = 'Hello';

if (isset($_POST['check'])) {
    $check = "yes";
} else {
    $check = "no";
}

$message .= "<br>"."<br>";
$message .= "<strong>Date and time:</strong> ".$send_date ."<br/>";
$message .="<strong>Name:</strong> ".$_POST['name']."<br/>";
$message .="<strong>Phone: </strong> ".$_POST['phone']."<br/>";
$message .="<strong>Email: </strong> ".$_POST['email']."<br/>";
$message .="<strong>Agree to post ads:</strong> ".$check."<br/>";

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8"' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: someone@somewhere.com' . "\r\n";

mail($to, $subject, $message,$headers);


/*-----
echo 'The message was send <br>
Click <a href="index.php">here</a> to return on home page.';
window.location.href=""
-----*/
$_SESSION['thankyou']='Your email has been sent successfully';
header ('Location: index.php');
}

?>
```

But when I run the JS code , the email is not sent .

1. Is there a way to send the mail , without using some kind of an email client in the client's side ?
2. How can I fix this code ? thanks

Comment: This is because post variables are empty!

Comment: @ChethanN: I don't understand , which ? where ?

Answer (score 0):

You are issuing an HTTP GET request to the PHP handler, while the PHP handler requires that it is executed with HTTP POST and with appropriate POST variables. Try POSTing to the URL with the right variables.

(Also, you should add a special unique signature to prevent the form from being used to spam).

Comment: You mean `$.post("../sendMail.php");` ?

Comment: Yes, but you need to send additional info (post variables)

Comment: @ron, I tend to use VanillaJS, so I'm not familiar with the jQuery syntax for it, but most likely yes (of course, you are still missing the parameters in this example).

Comment: @MichaelAaronSafyan: Notice the `else` in the `php` file , if I submit nothing then there are default variables .

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
$.post( "../sendMail.php", { name: "John", phone: "1234", email:"abc@test.com" } );
```